# In Magento, I want to write some code to display the stock levels per category

Tags: php, magento, categories

I have searched the internet 3 times over and still nothing. I simply want to write some logic which will display each category and how much stock is available for each category. If there are any smart people out there who can shed some light on this tricky problem, please feel free to answer at will.

Comment: Interesting question...If you have a few products in each category, which stock level should it show (the product with the most, least)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudo Code (Assuming that you are trying to display how much stock each item has)

```
 $category_id = 1;
 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
 $totalStockLevel = 0;
 // get all product within that category 
 $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($category);
 foreach($productCollection as $product){
     // load stock
     $stockLevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()
      // do you logics here
      $totalStockLevel += $stockLevel;
  }

  echo $totalStockLevel;
```

To get all categories see http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/24947/

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/196846/#t247851